# Microsoft Word: TOC and hyperlinks messed up

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, table-of-contents

My table of content in Microsoft Word is reshaped like what is shown in the picture.

[image]

At the same time my hyperlinks in Word started to appear like this:

[image]

I tried "toggle field codes", but it didn't solve the problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled Office, but the problem still persists. What should I do?

Comment: I'm unsure how you tried to toggle field codes. Rich Michaels' answer is correct and should help. If you want, I have a free Add-In that automatically shifts to view field results rather than codes. http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#FieldCodesHide

Comment: Thank you Charles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Word > File > Options > Advanced and in the **Show document content** group make sure the checkbox for **Show Field codes instead of their values** is clear.

[image]

Comment: man, you saved my life. It was OK just a couple of days ago. I don't know what happened.

Comment: On a Windows system, Alt+F9 will do the same thing.   http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Function